# MSSQL join with itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

t1 AND t2

```
id | related_id
1  | 2
1  | 3
```

Where t2 is relationship table between t1 records. What is the best way to get desired output?

```
t1.id | t1_copy.id
1     | NULL -- want to get this NULL row
1     | 2
1     | 3
```

Simple `JOIN` would almost work, however it doesn't give me the first `NULL` row.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1_copy.id FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t1 t1_copy ON t1_copy.id = t2.related_id
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

P.S: Yes, I do realize that desired output is wacky.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is the `NULL` supposed to be where the `4` record would go, if it had a row in `t2`?

Comment: @voithos, `NULL` supposed to be there, added `WHERE` clause to my query to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple UNION should do the trick

```
SELECT
   id, 
   null as copy_id
FROM
   t1 
WHERE
  exists (select * from t2 where t1.id = t2.id)
UNION ALL
SELECT
   t1.id,
   t2.related_id
FROM
   t1 
   INNER JOIN t2
   ON t1.id = t2.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85c77/5)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1_copy.id FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = 1
```

Comment: Might be wrong, but I also do not think this will work correctly.